# React.js - Bootstrap render component in Nav

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am a bit stuck here.
I am using React bootstrap, [Navigation component](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navigation)

I have a route called dashboard. That route is protected, available only via login.

When the user navigates to Dahsboard, this is what I have accomplished:
[image]

I would like to achieve something like this:
[image]

So when user clicks BOM X-ray it renders small components Children 1,2 and 3.

This is the code that renders first image:

```
import React from 'react'
import Bom from './bomxray/Indexbom';

import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Nav';
import NavItem from 'react-bootstrap/lib/NavItem';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/lib/NavDropdown';
import MenuItem from 'react-bootstrap/lib/MenuItem';

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
   handleSelect(event, selectedKey) {
       //event.preventDefault();
       alert('selected ' + selectedKey);
   }
render() {
    return (
        <Nav bsStyle="tabs" activeKey={1} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} >Bom X-Ray</NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={2} title="Item">Calculation</NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={3} disabled>NavItem 3 content</NavItem>
            <NavDropdown eventKey={4} title="Dropdown" id="nav-dropdown">
                <MenuItem eventKey="4.1">Action</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem eventKey="4.2">Another action</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem eventKey="4.3">Something else here</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem divider />
                <MenuItem eventKey="4.4">Separated link</MenuItem>
            </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
    );
 }
export default Dashboard
```

My idea is to create component:

```
import Bom from './bomxray/Indexbom';
```

And Bom component will have the Children inside. Those children will be CRUD Ajax to a server.

I tried things like this (FAIL):

```
 <NavItem eventKey={1} <Bom />>Bom X-Ray</NavItem>
```

And this (renders it, but all is messed up):

```
<NavItem eventKey={1} >Bom X-Ray</NavItem> <Bom />
```

If I am on the right track, please some idea how to proceed. If I am on totally wrong track, please point me to right direction :)

EDIT (Added possible solution).
Just occured to me, I do have:

```
handleSelect(event, selectedKey) {       
    alert('selected ' + selectedKey);
}
```

Could I somehow dynamicaly render the component? In the handeSelect I catch what ws clicked and based on that render component?

Comment: To me it seems like rendering a bunch of components inside the nav could cause a formatting nightmare.  Is it possible for you to render the `bom` components in a separate div outside the nav?

Comment: Of course. I am open to all ideas and suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you render the `<Bom/>` component outside of the `<Nav>`, as below, to preserve the formatting of your Nav.  You can control which of the components is showing through the `handleSelect` function by setting an `activeKey` in state.

```
 class Dashboard extends React.Component {
    getInitialState(){
        return({activeKey: 1})
    }
    handleSelect(selectedKey, event) {
        //event.preventDefault();
        alert('selected ' + selectedKey);
        this.setState({activeKey: selectedKey});
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Nav bsStyle="tabs" activeKey={this.state.activeKey} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
                    <NavItem eventKey={1} >Bom X-Ray</NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventKey={2} title="Item">Calculation</NavItem>
                    <NavItem eventKey={3} disabled>NavItem 3 content</NavItem>
                    <NavDropdown eventKey={4} title="Dropdown" id="nav-dropdown">
                        <MenuItem eventKey="4.1">Action</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey="4.2">Another action</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem eventKey="4.3">Something else here</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem divider />
                        <MenuItem eventKey="4.4">Separated link</MenuItem>
                    </NavDropdown>
                </Nav>

                {this.state.activeKey == 1 ? <Bom/> : null}
                {this.state.activeKey == 2 ? <CalculationComponent/> :null}
            </div>

        );
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am going to have more components. Second Nav item is Calculation, which is similar lik Bom component. How would I go about rendering it as well?

Comment: I've made edits to make the code example more complete.  Let me know if it addresses your question.

Comment: I will test it. On a side note, I just had an idea how to do it, and I made edit in my question. thing is I did not know how to do it... But you answered it :)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I hade to change declaration from class Dashboard extends React.Component {  to const Dashboard = React.createClass ({
Does it make any difference whatsoever?

Comment: I think your `handleSelect` arguments are reversed, it should be (selectedKey, event): https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navs-props